# Not call onMessageReceived (FCM) when app is not running

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
            android:name=".CustomFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

My service:

```
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage
import org.tokend.template.BuildConfig

    class CustomFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
        private val TAG = CustomFirebaseMessagingService::class.java.name
    
      
        override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived:")
       ...
    }
```

And when app is running and FCM is received then success called method `onMessageReceived`

Nice.

But when app is not running then method `onMessageReceived` is not called.

From server send different message type: **data**, **notification**. Not help. Not call `onMessageReceived` when app is **NOT RUNNING**

Comment: Note that this depends on the type of message received: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: @Michael Not help. It's describe how show push when app is in the background. But not how show  push when app is not running.

Comment: `onMessageReceived` won't be called unless your app is in the foreground, except if the message only contains a data payload. That's just the way it works. In other scenarios, the message will be handled by the system notification tray.

Comment: @Michael Do you mean that I need create my service that extend BroadcastReceiver to handle firebase cloud message when app is not running?

Comment: No. I'm saying the system notification tray will take of showing the notification for you in that scenario. If you don't want that behavior, send data messages instead.

Comment: @Michael Nothing show (if app not running). Not show any message on system tray.

Comment: @a_subscriber What is your test device?

Comment: @Ziem Google Pixel 3a (Android 10)