# Android FirebaseMessagingService is not called when app is in background

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In Android, I am using firebase notification service for push notification. The message need to modify/amend with custom data and will display to the user. I am doing it in onMessageReceived() as in below link

[Firebase notification Sample](https://medium.com/@Codeible/android-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-914623716dea)

I can able to get messages and amend it if the data message content only (shd not include notification payload) when app is in foreground or background.

[Android notification issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62673252/not-call-onmessagereceived-fcm-when-app-is-not-running)

Is there any possibility/alternative way to modify the messages with notification and data payload info? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't change notifications content when the app is not in the foreground because `onMessageReceived` is not called. However, you can modify the payload on the launcher activity.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved can you explain a bit. if possible share the source code. I am novice in android development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by using Data message only. Avoid notification payload.